# mecabのユーザー辞書追加をしても反映されません。

Tags: mecab

環境はMac OS High Sierraです。
mecabで辞書を新しく登録するために、下記のようなcsv(utf-8)をつくり、ユーザー辞書として追加しました。

```
肝機能障害,,,0,名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
```

下記のような形で実行しています。

```
➜  userdic /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index \
-d /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic \
-u /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/userdic/medical.dic \
-f utf-8 -t utf-8 medical_terms.csv
reading medical_terms.csv ... 1
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|

done!
➜  userdic ls
medical.dic       medical_terms.csv

➜  userdic echo '肝機能障害' | mecab -u medical.dic -N2
肝      接頭詞,名詞接続,*,*,*,*,肝,カン,カン
機能    名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,機能,キノウ,キノー
障害    名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,障害,ショウガイ,ショーガイ
EOS
肝      名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,肝,キモ,キモ
機能    名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,機能,キノウ,キノー
障害    名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,障害,ショウガイ,ショーガイ
EOS
```

上記のようにmecab-dict-indexは問題なく実行できています。IPA品詞体系は問題ないはずです。コストの問題も考え、-N2オプションもつけていますが、やはり今回作成したユーザー辞書が反映されていないようです。

他にどういった原因が考えられますでしょうか？どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/122940

Answer (score 1):

ユザー辞書は作成されていますが、その辞書が使われていません。

mecabのuserdicに作成したのならば、mecabの設定ファイルに登録しましょう。

設定の方法は、[mecabのマニュアル](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic.html)の以下の部分です。

> /home/foo/bar/foo.dic ができていることを確認
>   /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic/dicrc もしくは /usr/local/etc/mecabrcに以下を追加
>
> userdic = /home/foo/bar/foo.dic
>
> /usr/local/etc/mecabrc を編集する権限が無い場合は /usr/local/etc/mecabrc を ~/.mecabrc にコピーし, 上記のエントリを追加
>
> userdic はCSVフォーマットデ複数指定可能 
>    userdic = /home/foo/bar/foo.dic,/home/foo/bar2/usr.dic,/home/foo/bar3/bar.dic

また、カレントディレクトリーにおいて -u オプションを付けて使いたい場合は、辞書が作成されるフォルダーをカレントディレクトリーにします。

```
userdic /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index \
-d /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic \
-u medical.dic \
-f utf-8 -t utf-8 medical_terms.csv
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘頂いた登録は行なっております。また今回はecho '肝機能障害' | mecab -u medical.dic -N2で新しいユーザー辞書を明示している状態です。

Comment: userdic の方は -u /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/userdic/medical.dic なので/usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/userdic/ ディレクトリに辞書が作成されます。
一方 mecab -u medical.dic はホームディレクトリーのmedical.dicが使われます。作成した辞書と使っている辞書が違うと思われます。